# Excel passthru in IBM Datapower

Tags: excel, ibm-datapower

I received requirement to pass thru excel (.xlsx) in IBM datapower and transfer over AS2.
Polling from SFTP and do no modification and pass it over AS2.

I never implemented excel (.xlsx) in datapower . Is this possible if yes what action need to be used in datapower?

Answer (score 0):

`.xlsx` is actually XML so you can (if you want) treat it as XML but I would recommend to use `non-xml` in any case to also support `.xls` as well as not having any DataPower rules/validations messing with your `xlsx` messages.

You didn't mention if you use B2B Gateway, but if so it is `non-xml` per default so you wouldn't need to do any changes at all. Just configure the B2B Partner for AS2.